# Google API to query user's authorized OAuth scope?

Tags: api, oauth

I am using OAuth to access Google's API (IMAP, contacts, etc), assuming I have an authorized access token for a specific user, is there any API to query Google for all the scope that the user authorized for my application?

Also, is there any way to detect (or get notified) when a user revokes access to my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no API call to know what access your application has. Also when a user revokes access to your app you will start getting HTTP 401 when making the API calls which you can catch and ask the user to authorize again.